# How to display recently created layers in GDB?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-pro, file-geodatabase

This is cross posted [here](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/how-to-display-recently-created-layers-in-gdb/m-p/1250539#M64527).

What I've done is split a layer by attributes into a recently created GDB. Depending on the layer it will create a multitude of layers in the GDB. What I want to do is add the layers that are created in the GDB to the map. The name of the layers will change everytime the script is run. What I don't understand is how to add the list of layers to:

```
arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(in_features, out_layer, {where_clause}, {workspace}, {field_info})
```

I need to add them to map to for further processing mainly changing symbology, grouping and packaging.

Edit-

This will list all the features in the GDB

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r'location\File.gdb'
GDB = arcpy.env.workspace

full_fcs = []
for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    full_fcs.append(os.path.join(GDB,fc))
print(full_fcs)
```

Comment: Use the function ListFeatureClasses() to read the datasets in your geodatabase into a python list, then step over that running the make featurelayer tool.

Comment: import os


import arcpy


# Set the workspace for ListFeatureClasses


arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/base"


# Use the ListFeatureClasses function to return a list of
#  shapefiles.


featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

How do I setp it over to makefeaturelayer?

Comment: Not to nitpick on semantics, but proper terminology helps reduce confusion and leads to better responses.  Layers are not in geodatabases, data sets are in them (feature classes, tables, mosaics, etc...).  Also, the edit to the question doesn't list "all the features in the GDB", in fact it lists none of them.  What the code does is list the names of feature classes in the geodatabase.  If you wanted to list "all the features", you would have to use cursors to iterate over each feature class.

Answer (score 0):

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r'\\Path\Tracks.gdb'
GDB = arcpy.env.workspace

full_fcs = []
for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    full_fcs.append(os.path.join(GDB,fc))
print(full_fcs)

serials = []
for i in full_fcs:
    serials.append(i.split("\\")[-1])

**SOLUTION 1**

for path, name in zip(full_fcs, serials):
    arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(path, name)

**SOLUTION 2**

for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, f"{fc}")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I suggest learning and using [Walk - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/walk.htm).  It matches the behavior or Python's `os.walk()`, and doesn't rely on setting the environment workspace.

Comment: For solution 2, I would ensure that your SQL object is wrapped to prevent syntax errors. `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, f"'{fc}'"`